# No se despliega una imagen en HTML Visual Studio 2022

Tags: img

No puedo lograr que se despliegue una imagen, en ningún navegador, con la etiqueta <img ... >. Como pueden observar, las rutas son las correctas, creo yo, pero igual no presenta nada cuando se abre el navegador. Utilizo Visual Studio 2022. Siempre sale el texto entre comillas que coloco luego del "alt".

He probado con otro Editor de HTML y despliega las imágenes en dos de tres navegadores. En el que no despliega es en FireFox.

*Código:*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";   
<html>
<body>
    <style>
    .bloc{ 
        background-image: url("C:\Users\Pro\source\repos\Etiquetas\Pages\Vani.jpg");
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 5px;
        width: 250px;
        color: mediumvioletred;
        }
    </style>
<div class="bloc">
 <img src="C:\Users\Pro\source\repos\Etiquetas\Imagenes\Vani.jpg" alt="imagen 0">
<h1 class="display-2">Welcome</h1>

    <br /> <img src="C://Users/Pro/source/repos/Etiquetas/pages/Vani.jpg" alt="Imagen 1" usemap="#workmap" width="200" height="10"><br />
<p> <br /> <img src="C:\Users\Pro\source\repos\Etiquetas\Imagenes\Vani.jpg" alt="Imagen 2" ;> </p><br />
    <img src="C:\\Users\Pro\Escritorio\mem2.jpg" width="200" height="10" alt="Imagen 3"><br />
    <img src="C:\Users\Pro\source\repos\Etiquetas\Pages\Vani.jpg" alt="Imagen 4" usemap="#workmap" width="200" height="50"><br />

<img src="https://www.jimdo.com/es/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/FreeImages-714x402.jpeg" alt="xxx " />
</div>
</body>
</html>}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tenes la extension 'Path Intellisense' instalada? es una extensión que te permite autocompletar rutas de archivos siempre y cuando uses rutas relativas es decir, que tomen como referencia el directorio raiz de tu proyecto, estas rutas comienzan con './'

Comment: Si no hay fallos en las rutas entonces el problema debe estar en otro lado, proba usando rutas relativas con Path Intellisense

Comment: Hola Ivan, lo ideal, es que copies tu carpeta de imágenes en el mismo directorio que está el **html**, y luego usas: **<img src="/Imagenes/Vani.jpg" alt="imagen 0">**.

Comment: Las rutas las obtengo del mismo Visual Studio. Si colocas el ratón en el archivo y con click derecho te da la ruta completa. Con otro Editor de HTML las rutas funcionan y se muestra la imagen.

Comment: Hola Marce. No funcionó tu sugerencia. Pero aprecio mucho las respuestas de todos, ya he probado, antes de plantear la pregunta, con todas las recomendaciones pero no funcionan. Recuerden que la etiqueta y las rutas las probé en el Notepad++ y con ese Editor las imágenes se despliegan. Solo con el Visual no da resultado.